React Native expo-camera scanning Qr Code but not able to scan Barcode
I am able to scan QR code with expo-camera but not able to scan barcode .handleBarCodeScanned() methos is called for QR code but not for barcode .
My code :
<View style= {{height: 100}}><CameraView
        onBarcodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
        barcodeScannerSettings={{
          barcodeTypes: ["qr", "pdf417","codabar","aztec","datamatrix","code39"],
        }}
        style={styles.camera}
      /> 
       </View>
const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    console.log("barcode scanned");
    setScanned(true);
    alert(`Bar code with type ${type} and data ${data} has been scanned!`);
  };


TO Scan Barcode Images just remove barcodeScannerSettings. This resolved my problem .

Maybe ean13 ? you can try ignore barcodeScannerSettings to accept all types.
By the way, must steady hold, great focus, really hard to detect more than qr code.
--- edit add sample code --
<CameraView style={{flex: 1, }}
onBarcodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
>
</CameraView>


do you have a sample code for general setting?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
